# TCP Servers: Drop Connection, instead of resetting or responding?

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, solaris

Is it possible in Node.JS to "drop" a connection in such a way that

- The client never receives a response (200, 404 or otherwise)
- The client is never notified that the connection is terminated (never receives connection reset or end of stream)
- The server's resources are released (the server should not attempt to maintain the connection in any way)

I am specifically asking about Node.JS HTTP Servers (which are really just complex TCP servers) on Solaris., but if there are cases on other OSes (Windows, Linux) or programming languages (C/C++, Java) that permit this, I am interested.

Why do I want this?

To annoy or slow down (possibly single-threaded) robots such as [phpMyAdmin Probe](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7082/information-on-the-phpmyadmin-probe).

I know this is not really something that matters, but these types of questions can better help me learn the boundaries of my programs.

I am aware that the client host is likely to re-transmit the packets of the connection since I am never sending reset.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can just .. not respond. If you won't res.anything() then the client won't get any response (200, 400 etc), no headers will be sent.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that would still tie up an OS resource marking an open connection, and eventually run out out of either Memory or TCP Ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not possible in a generic TCP stack (vs. your own custom TCP stack). The reasons are:

1. Closing a socket sends a RST
2. Even if you avoid sending a RST, the client continues to think the connection is open while the server has closed the connection. If the client sends *any* packet on this connection, the server is going to send a RST.

You may want to explore firewalling these robots and block / rate limit their IP addresses with something like iptables (linux) or the equivalent on solaris.

Comment: Your number 2 is a very good point. I guess I would have too look at live rule additions. I could add a temporary rule for the current connections source and destination IPs and ports. This would cause the intended hang on the current connection and still allow new ones through. Now I just have to wait until I get around to a software firewall and then I have to decide whether I want to do this or not.

Comment: Yup, some kind of live rule addition is useful here. A web server like apache also has built-in rate-limit options.

Answer (score 1):

closing a connection should NOT send an RST. There is a 3 way tear down process.