# Does the server reattempt sending of the TCP "connection closed" packet?

Tags: tcp

If there is a firewall dropping the server's connection reset packet, does the resend? Does it just send the packet and forget about it, only re-sending if the client tries using that connection that the server closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of other stimuli, a TCP Reset should only be sent once.  There is no acknowledgement for it, so the server has no way to know it was dropped.

In the case of a client trying to maintain the connection, the server would send another Reset, but that won't matter if the firewall keeps dropping them

Comment: That is what I thought. I was just making sure. I wanted to make sure I did not shoot myself in the foot [when adding live rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127336/tcp-servers-drop-connection-instead-of-resetting-or-responding).